# Facebook App can't find Appstore ID

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I'm developing a iOS App right now and got some awkward things going on with Facebook.

The App is using the Facebook Login and therefore I need to add the
`Bundle-ID`, `iPhone Store-ID` and `iPad Store-ID` in the Facebook App so I can use the login in my native app.

**like so:** http://puu.sh/rE4oW/bfba72feb3.png

**Error:** "There was a problem fetching your iPhone Store ID from the App Store. Please check the ID and try again later."

But I can't add the appstore id because Facebook doesn't find this in the store.
This is right because the app is not listed in the store right now.

But how should I implement the login without releasing the app in to the app store?

I am confused..

Comment: did u follow facebook.developer documentation ?

Comment: How did you set the IDs if your app isn't in the app store yet?

Comment: If the app is not in the app store Facebook will of course not be able to find it

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Facebook Login, that you can't leave it blank.
But what you can do is set it to 0.

Release the app and then you should have your iPhone Store Id & iPad Store Id, so you can change it then.

References of people facing the same issue:
https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/43922-facebook-unable-to-retrive-iphone-store-id/

**Please Note:**
After reading about it, my recommendation is that you release this feature after your first App Store release. Because a non-working released feature is way worse than limited features.

Rest is upto you. Cheers!